# unable to inject a dynamic componant in a grid colomn

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to inject dynamically a select dropdown componant to the grid colomn evrytime I create a new row. Actually the dropdown componant is always injected to the same row.

My objectif is to remove the selected value from the available list everytime I create a new row

My parent componant I have:

```
export class ReferenceTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {

observable: Observable<any>;

@ViewChild('selectorTarget', {read: ViewContainerRef}) selectorTarget;

// colors
@Input() public datas: Array<string>;

public availableColors: Array<string>;

@Input() public styleId: string;

@Input() public headList: Array<string>;

public rows: Array<any> = [{}];

public rowIDs: Array<any> = [];


constructor(private _cr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.computeAvailableColors();
}

addRow() {
    this.rows.push({});
    const select: ComponentRef<SelectOptionsComponent> =
        this.selectorTarget.createComponent(
            this._cr.resolveComponentFactory(SelectOptionsComponent)
        );
    select.instance.availableColors = this.availableColors;
    select.instance.color = this.rows[0].color;
    select.instance.changed.subscribe(evt => {
        this.availableColors = this.availableColors.filter(c => c !== evt.color);
    });
}

computeAvailableColors() {
    this.availableColors = _.concat([''], this.datas);
    this.rowIDs  = _.map(this.rows, 'color')
    this.availableColors = _.difference(this.availableColors, this.rowIDs);
    const select: ComponentRef<SelectOptionsComponent> =
        this.selectorTarget.createComponent(
            this._cr.resolveComponentFactory(SelectOptionsComponent)
        );
    select.instance.availableColors = this.availableColors;
    select.instance.color = this.rows[0].color;
    select.instance.changed.subscribe(evt => {
    this.availableColors = this.availableColors.filter(c => c !== 
    evt.color);
    });
}
}
```

Parent html:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div #selectorTarget></div>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let headItem of headList"><input class="input" 
            type='text' #qty/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

On the child componant I have:

```
@Component({
selector: 'kia-select-options',
template: `<div><select [(ngModel)]="color" 
(ngModelChange)="sendColorEvent($event)"> 
                // value is a string or number
                <option *ngFor="let obj of availableColors">{{obj}}</option>
           </select></div>`
})
export class SelectOptionsComponent {

// couleurs
@Input() public availableColors: Array<string>;

@Input() public color: string;

@Output()
public changed = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private injector: Injector) {
}

sendColorEvent(color) {
    console.log(event)
    this.changed.emit({ color: color });
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by injecting all the table block in child componant instead of just the selector div

so now in the child template I have:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-scroll default-cursor">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select [(ngModel)]="color" (ngModelChange)="sendColorEvent($event)">
                        <option *ngFor="let obj of availableColors">{{obj}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td *ngFor="let headItem of headList"><input class="input" type='text' #qty/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```